# Implementing OData JSON interface on Django (Python)

Tags: python, django, json, odata

We would like to have a [OData JSON interface](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/json-format) on our Django (Python 2.5.4) website. At the moment of writing there seems to be [no library available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115506/odata-python-library-available).

I'm thinking of writing "some" logic to handle this ourselves.

- Would it be a good idea to extend the Django JSON serializer?
- Where and how to store the URI's related to the models?

Comment: We did decide it was not worth the time & money to implement it at the time. I'm no longer working on the project so unfortunately I can't help you with this. If you do find/have a way to implement this be sure to put it here, I'll be happy to accept your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea to extend the Django JSON serializer, but have a look at [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) this might be the better route to go.

The URI's will have to be defined in your urls.py for your app, and then in your models you could define a function

get_odata_uri()

Which would work like the Django's [get_absolute_url()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).  Instead of hardcoding it into your model, make sure you make use of the reverse function from django.core.urlresolvers