# Python framework for implementing Open Data Protocol (OData) consumers & producers

Tags: python, odata

Does anybody know about a Python framework for implementing Open Data Protocol (OData) (http://www.odata.org/) consumers & producers?´

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4115506/69772.